# Add column to groupby dataframe based on length of sliced column

Tags: python, pandas

I've looked at other questions regarding similar topics, but I have yet found an answer. So I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], ['some text', 'other text', 'more text', 'new text', 'text sample', 'sample', 'sample text'], ['kw1, kw2', 'kw1, kw2, kw3', 'kw1', 'kw1, kw2, kw3, kw4', 'kw1', 'kw1, kw2, kw3', 'kw1, kw2']), columns=['value', 'cluster', 'text', 'keywords'])
>>> result = df.groupby(['value', 'cluster', 'text']).keywords.sum().to_frame()
>>> result =
value      cluster      text      keywords
  1           0      some text       kw1, kw2
                     other text      kw1, kw2, kw3
                     more text       kw1
              1      new text        kw1, kw2, kw3, kw4
  2           0      text sample     kw1
                     sample          kw1, kw2, kw3
              1      sample text     kw1, kw2
```

What I would like to do next based on my above mentioned question is to add a column with a list of lists to this existing dataframe based on the sliced columns value and cluster, instead of the text or keyword columns.

```
>>> summary = [['some, summary'], ['this, too, summ'], ['kws, of, summ'], ['summ, based, kw']]
```

I basically want to match each item of the summary list to a cluster. So it would look like this:

```
value      cluster   summary            text       keywords
  1           0      some, summary    some text       kw1, kw2
                                      other text      kw1, kw2, kw3
                                      more text       kw1
              1      this, too, summ   new text        kw1, kw2, kw3, kw4
  2           0      kws, of, summ    text sample     kw1
                                      sample          kw1, kw2, kw3
              1      summ, based, kw  sample text     kw1, kw2
```

Obviously the "simple" adding of a column to a dataframe does not work because the length of the list of lists to be added is not matching the dataframe length.

```
result['summary'] = summary
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (7)
```

I also tried to use the following method, but it just adds together all keywords from one cluster, which is not exactly what I am looking for.

```
result['summary'] = result.groupby(['value', cluster']).transform('sum')
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), join with `summary` , add to `MultiIndex`:

```
a = result.index.get_level_values('value').astype(str)
b = result.index.get_level_values('cluster').astype(str)
result['summary'] = 'summary ' + a + '.' + b

result= result.set_index('summary', append=True).reorder_levels([0,1,3,2])
print (result)
                                                 keywords
value cluster summary     text                           
1     0       summary 1.0 more text                   kw1
                          other text        kw1, kw2, kw3
                          some text              kw1, kw2
      1       summary 1.1 new text     kw1, kw2, kw3, kw4
2     0       summary 2.0 sample            kw1, kw2, kw3
                          text sample                 kw1
      1       summary 2.1 sample text            kw1, kw2
```

EDIT: If length of list is same like number of groups is possible use:

```
print (len(summary) == result.groupby(['value','cluster']).ngroup().max() + 1)
True
```

Create dict by `enumerate` with select first value of one element list:

```
d = {k: v[0] for k, v in enumerate(summary)}
print (d)
{0: 'some, summary', 1: 'this, too, summ', 2: 'kws, of, summ', 3: 'summ, based, kw'}
```

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
result['summary'] = result.groupby(['value','cluster']).ngroup().map(d)
result= result.set_index('summary', append=True).reorder_levels([0,1,3,2])
print (result)
                                                     keywords
value cluster summary         text                           
1     0       some, summary   more text                   kw1
                              other text        kw1, kw2, kw3
                              some text              kw1, kw2
      1       this, too, summ new text     kw1, kw2, kw3, kw4
2     0       kws, of, summ   sample            kw1, kw2, kw3
                              text sample                 kw1
      1       summ, based, kw sample text            kw1, kw2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated the summary list because my example was easy to misinterpret. I will however try out the other parts of your answer and see if I can make my code running with it.

Comment: @coding_anon - answer was edited.